# Remove comma at end of line in sed on MacOS?

Tags: macos, catalina, unix

I created a file in TextEdit on the Mac called stuff.txt:

```
stuff and stuff
More stuff
Stuff with a , in the middle
Stuff with a comma at the end,
More stuff
```

If I run this command:

```
cat stuff.txt | sed 's/,$//'
```

then the output is

```
stuff and stuff
More stuff
Stuff with a , in the middle
Stuff with a comma at the end
More stuff
```

I have another file created by grepping various .eml files created by Save As in Thunderbird on the Mac:

```
grep '@' *.eml | grep -v 'From' | grep -v 'Message-ID' | sed 's/^.*: //' > output.txt
```

Running `cat output.txt | sed 's/,$//'`
does not remove final commas. Help?

More information:
I tried the `file` command on both files:

```
% file stuff.txt
stuff.txt: ASCII text
% file output.txt
output.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Comment: Does the second file have CRLF line endings? Or is there whitespace after the , ? Can you add a sample of the file?

Comment: @nohillside I tried the file command. It looks like my problem file has CRLF.

Comment: sed doesn’t work with those :-) There are several Q&A on how to change the line endings on the site (I‘m on the iPhone right now, is a bit difficult to search).

Comment: I fixed it by using cat in a terminal and copying and pasting the output into a new file.

Comment: It's simple - just match the carriage-return character after the comma. (Also you don't have to pipe, just give the filename to `sed`).  `sed  sed 's/,^M$//' x.txt`  To get that control-M in there, in `bash` I type ctrl-V ctrl-M.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like sed will not work on CRLF files (thanks @nohillside).

I fixed it by using cat in a terminal and copying and pasting the output into a new file.

Although the body of the text came from a Linux machine, odd that Mac Thunderbird should put CRLF in the To: line of the email.

Comment: Running `perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/;'` on the file would also work :-)

Comment: Or just add the `\r` to the pattern.